# How to shuffle the order of panes in a tmux window?

Tags: tmux

I would like to shuffle the order of panes in a tmux window.

I didn't find any instructions about it in the tmux help or cheatsheet, except for swapping specific panes.

Is there a way to shuffle the order of panes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate all the panes in a window by using the `rotate-window` command. I use the following binding to rotate all the panes in my window:

```
bind-key -n M-r rotate-window -Ut :+
```

(Alt+r rotates all panes in window)

Comment: Noting happens when I try it. I also tried just typing `CTRL+B` -> `rotate-window -Ut :+` and nothing happened

Comment: Which version of TMUX are you running? Can you upgrade?

Comment: I can't upgrade on the machine I need it. Indeed it is a version issue (it works on another machine).